# Android Studio seeing which files a change was applied to

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I was doing a code inspection with Android Studio and I accepted a change across multiple file which I now wish to undo.

When I go to VCS|Local History | Show History for one of the files, I can see the change was applied to 25 files, but I do not know how to show which files these are. I have version 0.3.5

[image]

Answer (score 104):

Right click on your project in project structure on the left. then Local History -> Show History. If you want to show history only for src folder, click on it.. the same for layout folder etc..

[image]

Comment: This is why Android Studio is waaay better than Eclipse.

Comment: @RyanHeitner if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it.

Comment: I recommend using git as the best solution for version control related problems.

Comment: You are save my life!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Shelve changes**.

This is a great tool to view your changes.

---

Here is how to open the 'Shelve changes' dialog in Android Studio :

[image: How to open Git shelf on Android Studio]

---

And here is what the dialog looks like :

[image: Dialog]

You can also use this box to commit your changes if you want.