# Remove Activity from Inner Class (Android Studio)

Tags: android

Currently working on Android Studio, I accidentally placed one of my activities as an inner class of another activity instead of transferring to the package. Now I can't seem to find that activity. How do I retrieve it?

Comment: `Now I can't seem to find that activity` use search to find it by name for example

Comment: You try and see if its in still in local history, look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25076685/4056108