# Is it possible to recover overwritten files from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, file-recovery

For a mistake i've overwritten my two project that has same names from android studio and i've dismissed that action today i've tryed to open the main project and i've found no Java classes in it and just the layout's files.

While in the second project to which i was overwritting there is a huge confusion of files and trying to recover the project version by using history of Android Studio even those files has disappeared.

Is it possible in anyway to recover the whole project?

*Ps: all that remain from that project is a generated apk.*

Comment: Which OS do you have?

Comment: @RoyalGriffin Windows 10

Answer (score 3):

I have some solutions that may work.

Candidates are:

- Search for `$AppData$` folders
- Search for registries
- (Hardest) you may have to preserve the disk state and carve the files yourself..

Cheers, and hope it helped..!

**To use the third method(file carving), you may not cause many file operations occur!!(The system may overwrite the previous data)**

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you used source control such as [git](https://git-scm.com/) or [svn](https://subversion.apache.org/) and it is a simple matter of reverting to the last commit you made, however that is done in your chosen source control. If you don't use source control, perhaps this will serve as a lesson to do so in the future.

I've not used Android Studio, but as a JetBrains product like IntelliJ, it will have a [local history record of changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25076685/8182370). But that would only record very recent changes.

If that doesn't work, you may have to find out if your chosen operating system backed up the files in a restore point etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you have turned on the file history, you can use that to go to a previous version of the folder. Can also use system restore to go back to a previous date. Can also use third party softwares such as Recuva to get deleted files back.
Make sure to keep a copy of current state somewhere before trying these out.