# Android Studio overwritten a whole project

Tags: android, android-studio

I was working on a project and I needed some to implement some functionality that I used in a previous project so I opened the old project in a new window but what Android Studio did was overwriting the old project's code with some code from the new project and the rest was just gibberish, I have never seen this before.

If it of any help it's been a while since the last time I opened the old project on android studio

Below you will find a snapshop of one of classes (they're all messed up just like this one)

So, What is exactly this and is there any possible fixes? I have no Backup of the project

What I tried:

- Cleaning
- Building and rebuilding
- Invalidating caches
- Syncing with system files
- Restarting PC/Android studio multiple times
  But so far no luck

[image]

Comment: Hope it may help you -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53540268/2919483'

Comment: No VCS either? feels really bad man...