# Go back to APK compilation version, instead of actual commit

Tags: android, git, android-studio

Let's say I forgot to commit at the moment of compiling my APK.
I continued modifying my files, and then committed later on.
Can I go back to the precise moment of APK compilation, which is unfortunately between two commits?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it  - some things you can do is either go back to your old commits and start again(not recommended)or:

If the change was not so large you can see what exactly did you changed and start hard copy-pasting and return to your old version of the code.

But the best thing I can recommend is to use branches - start a production branch(only stable code goes there) and dev branch(in this branch you can modify your code as you want because you have another stable working branch)

**Edit:** as Zoe mentioned in one of the comments - check for [local history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973449/android-studio-seeing-which-files-a-change-was-applied-to) in your IDE (the link gives example for android studio IDE)

Comment: Thanks. I try to use branches as much as I can, but I guess I had a moment of devious behaviour, and now I regret it :s

Comment: branches can really save you a lot of time, and if my answer helped you please accept it so others with the same problem can know that this can help them too.

Comment: Local History might help.

Comment: Local history is a really good solution, in my answer I only mentioned the history working with git and forgot about the fact that a lot of IDE have local history saved - i will edit my answer, thank you