# destroyed gradle file(Module:PackageName) And Not Sync Project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I opened my project today and came across this problem:
The `gradle (Module: app)` file is healthy, but the other `gradle file` associated with the project is cluttered and corrupted.
The Codes of `gradle File(Project: PackageName)` is shown below:

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * gradle plugin from the resource data it found. It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */
package android.support.v7.appcompat;

public final class R {
private R() {}

public static final class anim {
    private anim() {}

    public static final int abc_fade_in = 0x7f010000;
    public static final int abc_fade_out = 0x7f010001;
    public static final int abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom = 0x7f010002;
    public static fi
```

This problem does not allow me to continue my work and stop me. Please help me faster. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use a versioning tools (git, mercury, svn, etc.), even if it is a practice/test project of yours, so that you can recover from these errors

Any case, you can still use Local History to recover this file if you are using Android Studio: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25076685/783707 . Simply go to Project structure, right click your file, click on Local History, and choose an older version of the file to go back to.